# Android randomly positioned Views in Layout

Tags: java, android, view, fragment

On Android I need to populate a fragment dynamically (programmatically) with a layout view item. Those items need to appear randomly positioned in the fragment screen, so I guess I need to set their params of position with a random function.

However, AbsoluteLayout is now deprecated and I don't see how can I consistently populate the fragment by setting a random position to each of those views. With RelativeLayout they're all relative to each other, with LinearLayout they all are ordered, with constraints layout would be chaotic to do this.

What would be the best way to populate a layout with randomly positioned views dynamically?

My background Layout is just a Constraint Layout with an image at the center. I need the other images to appear randomly in the screen.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/center"
        android:src="@mipmap/image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: what does your layout look like ?

Comment: @a_local_nobody I've edited my question with the layout

Comment: i was actually asking what the layout should look like eventually, can you perhaps use something like a grid/staggered grid layout